# Dynamic URL rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Migrating a site from IIS to Apache and I'm having trouble with a RewriteRule I can't find the answer to.

I need to redirect from `www.domain.com/pubs/books/P123.asp` to `www.domain.com/books.php?p=P123`.

No matter what I try, I'm getting a 404.

Can someone give me a pointer?  All the examples I seem to find have the dynamic part of the URL at the end.  Do I first need to strip the .asp?

Drupal is also running on this site so there is some RewriteRules there to.

The latest I have tried is: `RewriteRule /pubs/books/P(.*)$.asp /books.php?p=$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Read the documentation! You can find it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

It says:

> `Syntax:  RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`

and

> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
>   the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
>   string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context,
>   the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path,
>   after removing the prefix that led the server to the current
>   RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where
>   the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the
>   hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables
>   respectively.

(in other words: A pattern starting with a slash will never match if in .htaccess context)

---

First of all, make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and the rewriteengine is on (put `RewriteEngine on` in your .htaccess) and allowed there (see docs).

Assuming this is in a `.htaccess` in your www-root, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/books/P(.*)\.asp$ books.php?p=$1 [L]
```

The syntax `^...$` makes sure that this is the entire filesystem path. We wouldn't want to match `http://example.com/some/more/paths/pubs/books/P123.asp` here and rewrite that.

Comment: Many thanks.  In this case, the problem turned out to be a rule further up the .htaccess file meant it was never getting to this rule.  Your reply was helpful for the correct syntax also.